# How to refresh Query/Cache from an Apollo Subscription component in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Imagine an component hierarchy like so:

```
<Team>
  <Leaderboard />
  <PlayerStats />
</Team>
```

In the render method of Leaderboard, we have an Apollo/GraphQL Query component fetching the top players.

We also have an  [component](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions.html#api) that triggers upon getting a new PlayerStat (currently in PlayerStats -- but happy to put it anywhere).

How do I get the Leaderboard query to [refetchQueries](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates.html#refetchQueries)/clear cache upon a trigger from the PlayerStat Subscription component.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

So the Apollo Query component provides a `refetch` function with React context, just like `data`, `loading` and `error`.

```
<Query query={...} >
  {
    ({ data, loading, error, refetch}) => {
      if (!this.state.refetch) {
        this.setState({ refetch });
      }
      return <RenderData data={data} />;
    }
  }
</Query>
```

You can set this `refetch` function in the state and call it whenever the  component receives an event.

Comment: sorry -- still new to React, but is it good practice to setState in a render()

Comment: @Jonathan sorry my bad. I edited the answer.
You can do a conditional setState so that it does not go into a loop.
As you said, setState is not recommended to be used inside render. But I can't see any other way of modifying a sibling component other than that.